# How can I find out which processes are using my ports? Weird netstat output

Tags: webserver, netstat, port

I am trying to start a server that listens on 8080, but getting an error that the port is already in use. I am not running anything using that port.

Running `netstat -ano -p tcp | grep tcp6` shows something is using a bunch of ports but it doesn't give much info as to what.

Relevant output of `netstat -ano -p tcp | grep tcp6`:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8843                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                    off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::8880                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                    off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                    off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                    off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                    off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                    off (0.00/0/0)
```

Comment: What shows: ss -lptn 'sport = :8080' ?

Comment: `netstat -ln -eep -6` ?

Comment: Yet another option: `netstat -plnt | grep 8080`

Comment: YAO: `sudo lsof -itcp:8080`

Comment: All these commands should be run as root or won't find a process that is not running as the current user.

Comment: @A.B Indeed I was not running it as root, and running it as root showed which process was using it. Thanks for the help!